# How to log out from wordpress multiple site?

Tags: multisite

I install wordpress on domain name `www.example.com` then I have other domain name that point to the server of `www.example.com` too it might be `www.example1.com.uk` Problem is that when I log in from `www.example.com` other sites should be login too and if log out the the other site should logout also.
I any ideas pls!

Comment: Are these all site in a WordPress Multisite network? If so, then your users should automatically be logged in to all the sites. You might need to give them access to the various sites, though, if you've locked the content down.